# Range().value=.. not functioning. I get an error when it is supposed to fill the range with text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a code that looks for a word in a specific cell on a sheet. If the word is present, it should fill the specified range with text. I Cannot see the error but i get an error code called "Object required. The code in mention is below.

```
Sub SommerFerie()

Set wsOU = Worksheets("Overordnet ugeplan")
Set wsou1 = Worksheets("Sommertørn")

If Year(Date) = 2020 - 1 Then 'Sammenligner om det aktuelle år er 2020.
    If wsoul.Cells(6, 3).Value = "SIDVI" Then
        wsOU.Range("AD33:AD39, AE33:AE39, AF33:AF39").Value = "FERIE" 'Angiv hvor der skal fyldes ud.
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Add declaration for your worksheet variables.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` on the top of your module to avoid problems on variables.

Comment: Voted to close the question closed as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.` Please see [THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/dealing-with-questions-with-obvious-replies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to mispelling a variable. You have declared a variable named `wsou1`, but later in the code you're writing `wsoul`.

To avoid this kind of errors, I suggest to always put `Option Explicit` at the start of every module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typo error questions are not to be answered but closed as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.` Please see [THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/dealing-with-questions-with-obvious-replies)